# Scrapy - storing crawled pages as static files

Tags: scrapy

Apologies if this is a scrapy noob question but I have spent ages looking for the answer to this:

I want to store the raw data from each & every URL I crawl in my local filesystem as a separate file (ie response.body -> /files/page123.html) - ideally with the filename being a hash of the URL. This is so I can do further processing of the HTML (ie further parsing, indexing in Solr/ElasticSearch etc).

I've read the docs and not sure if there's a built-in way of doing this? Since the pages are by default being downloaded by the system it doesn't seem to make sense to be writing custom pipelines etc

Comment: You may want to have a look at [HttpCacheMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#filesystem-storage-backend)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As paul t said HttpCache Middleware might work for you but I'd advise writing you're own custom pipeline.

Scrapy has [built-in ways](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html) of exporting data to files but they're for json, xml and csv not raw html. Don't worry though it's not too hard!

provided your `items.py` looks somthing like:

```py
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Listing(Item):
    url = Field()
    html = Field()
```

and you've been saving your scraped data to those items in your spider like so:

```py
item['url'] = response.url
item['html'] = response.body
```

your `pipelines.py` would just be:

```py
import hashlib
class HtmlFilePipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # choose whatever hashing func works for you
        file_name = hashlib.sha224(item['url']).hexdigest()
        with open('files/%s.html' % file_name, 'w+b') as f:
            f.write(item['html'])
```

Hope that helps. Oh and don't forget to put a `files/` directory in your project root and add to your `settings.py` :

```py
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipeline.HtmlFilePipeline': 300,
}
```

source: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Comment: Great answer thanks - one small change, the ITEM_PIPELINES setting didn't work for me, I just changed it to 'myproject.pipeline**s**.HtmlFilePipeline' and it worked fine. Also worth noting the HttpCacheMiddleware saves the cache files in a hidden /.scrapy/ folder within the project.

Comment: @hammondos Thanks for the edit! If the answer worked would you mind accepting or giving it a vote? Trying to build these fake internet points is all :)

Comment: Don't have enough kudos to vote yet sorry, will accept answer, thanks again

Comment: @NKelner I want to do same, i followed our steps that u defined but not able to save web pages.Here i posted my configuration  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727634/using-scrapy-pipelines-not-able-to-write-crawled-web-pages-into-files    .Can you please have a look , and let me know what i am i doing wrong.